# DynamicPopulate with multiple triggers

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to dynamically populate a form field from multiple other fields in the form.

If input A **or** input B is changed, input C should be updated based on the values in input A **and** input B.

The DynamicPopulateExtender in Ajax control toolkit has almost this. With it I can populate a target based on a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with jQuery...

Comment: Why don't you share your solution then